# "cannot find code object on disk" after adding Swift libs in iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, jenkins, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I have a Jenkins job setup for my iOS project that used to build fine until i introduced a swift lib in my project.

I am getting the following error in Jenkins after adding the swift lib:

```
<Path>/TaxOnlineMobile.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib: cannot find code object on disk
*** error: Couldn't code sign <Path>/TaxOnlineMobile.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: code sign failed with exit code 1
```

Why do i get this error only after adding the swift lib? how do i resolve this? Please help!

---

***Please ignore the below part as it's the duplication of the above text. I'm doing this because stack overflow is not letting me post my question as it's too short. But it's naturally short.***

I have a Jenkins job setup for my iOS project that used to build fine until i introduced a swift lib in my project.

I am getting the following error in Jenkins after adding the swift lib:

```
<Path>/TaxOnlineMobile.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib: cannot find code object on disk
*** error: Couldn't code sign <Path>/TaxOnlineMobile.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: code sign failed with exit code 1
```

Why do i get this error only after adding the swift lib? how do i resolve this? Please help!